# Wait for all WPF animations to stop

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard

Given a WPF window, which may or may not have animations, I'd like to wait until they are all done before continuing processing.  Is there a generic way to do this.  Currently I can do something like this:

```
void WaitForAnimation(Storyboard storyboard)
{
    WaitUntil(() => storyboard.GetCurrentState() == ClockState.Stopped);
}
```

But this assumes I know the storyboards or have some way of finding them.  Is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion is that use Storyboard.Completed event to find out the completion of each story board.

Comment: Yes, but how do you get all the relevant storyboards?

Comment: gud question. let me search and if i get something useful i will let you know. pls update me if you get something.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just give your storyboards a x:Name and put them into a collection in codebehind? How many of them have you got?

Comment: This is a very generic problem. I am just given a window.  I don't know how many storyboards there will be--if any.

Comment: It is quite complicated then. A class inheriting from window may have storyboards created in codebehind as private properties or local variables. It can even animate without storyboards at all. To get a more general control of animations in your base class you'll have to enforce some contract. For example: Animate only using storyboards as resources - then it is easy to retrieve in code all storyboards with FindResource and check their state.